# Alternative to downthemall

Tags: updates, downloads

i used to download updates via synaptic mark all upgrades then save script because the internet is too slow here then open the generated file by firefox then i used downthemall manager to download all deb packages. Now downthemall no more availabe. Is there another way to download updates in the same way?

Answer (score 3):

You can download them using `wget` or `curl`, Synaptic Package Manager generates a shell script that you can execute in any GNU/Linux system.

[image: synaptic]

Here is the generated script:

[image: synaptic bash script]

If you're downloading these packages from a GNU/Linux based system, you can download all the files by using:

`chmod +x generated-script.sh`

`./generated-script.sh`

But if you prefer a browser plugin, then I recommend you to search here: https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/

Maybe this downloader could be useful for you: [Elite Download Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/elite-download-manager)

Hope it helps.

Comment: In this way i cannot resume and continue the download later

Comment: Yes, you can resume the download, the `-c` flag is for continue, you can verify it on the manual pages [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-resume-download), but, If you're talking about the web browser plugins, in that case, this tool has its limitations, so I recommend you again to use the shell script.

Answer (score 2):

uGet is a lightweight and very powerful download manager application. You can install uGet in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with this command:

```
sudo apt install uget
```

There is an option in the uGet settings to always show a uGet system tray icon in the notification area of the panel to the left of the clock and volume icons.

#### Features

- Resume downloads  – If your connection is interrupted, you can start right back where you left off with download resuming. (not guaranteed, it's server controlled and cannot be bypassed by a download manager)
- Queue downloads
- Classify downloads in categories
- Batch downloads
- Multi-Protocol – support for downloading files through HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, BitTorrent and Metalink
- Clipboard monitoring
- Import a list of URLs to download via .txt or .html files ✅

uGet also can be launched from the terminal with the command: `uget-gtk`

Comment: How can i generate  a txt or html file to import the list?

Comment: Generate a download script in Synaptic and then open the script in a text editor and remove everything except for the hyperlinks. The finished file must contain nothing but a list of links and each link needs to be on a separate line. Save the edited file as a .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DownThemAll! installing it in another browser that supports it, like ***Waterfox***, an open-source fork of Mozilla Firefox, that can install all Firefox extensions.

I described it in a video (https://youtu.be/OQ--UyyWbx8) on YouTube (in Italian language, but it's simple to follow the steps that I've done on my PC. In that case I'm using Linux Fedora 26 XFCE x64, but you can do the same under Window or MacOS).

Cheers